# GeoIP IPv4 database returning incorrect country codes - GeoIP update required?

Tags: php, location, ip, geoip

I am using the following code with the IPv4 database, however I am noticing a number of IP addresses coming with the wrong country code.

Is there a updated binary GeoIP database for IPv4?

Looking at http://maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/ it appears there are only updates for IPv6.

```
include("geoip.inc");

$gi = geoip_open("/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);

echo geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, "24.24.24.24") . "\t" .
     geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, "24.24.24.24") . "\n";
echo geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, "80.24.24.24") . "\t" .
     geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, "80.24.24.24") . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that GeoIP *do* update the IPv4 database and they are made available [here](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite). They state that they update it on the first Tuesday of every month and it is available for free.

I was probably using an old version of the binary database, and after updating it the IPs were returning the correct country code.